# How can I use JQuery to slide an IFRAME off the page without redrawing it?

Tags: jquery, html, css

On http://www.lastcalc.com I have an IFRAME to the right of the page, when you click on the "Hide Help" button in the top right the IFRAME slides off the page.  Clicking again slides the IFRAME back on.

The problem, at least in Chrome, is that the IFRAME's width seems to change as it is sliding off the page, which causes it to be redrawn as it slides - this isn't pretty.

This is the code I'm using to slide the IFRAME on and off the page:

```
$("DIV#help-button").click(function() {
        var helpIframe = $("IFRAME#helpframe");
        if (helpIframe.is(":visible")) {
            $('DIV#worksheet').width('100%');
            $("DIV#help-button span").text("Show Help");
            helpIframe.hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
        } else {
            $('DIV#worksheet').width('50%');
            $("DIV#help-button span").text("Hide Help");
            helpIframe.show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
        }
    });
```

Can anyone suggest how I can make this smoother by preventing the redraw of the IFRAME as it slides on/off the page?

Comment: Most likely, the reason why it is changing width is because you are using a % not a fixed value. Make sure the iFrames container also has a fixed value. Have a look at 'Inspect Element' in Chrome, and see what happens to the CSS when you click on the help button. this should give you enough info to fixe the issue.

Comment: In addition, is there any particular reason as to why you are using an iframe?

Comment: @BenCarey I'm using an IFRAME because the content comes from a separate URL - is there a better way?

Comment: AJAX! So easy to use. Have a look at this: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/. You can simply call a URL (with or without POST/GET parameters) and place the result into your document. Let me know if you need any help

Comment: @BenCarey Regarding width, I wanted to use a % to avoid arbitrary fixed constants - so that it would be flexible depending on the browser width.

Comment: Sure thing, always a challenge to get it work work nicely though! The first step here is to get the AJAX working, and then have a look at the width if it is still a problem

Comment: @BenCarey re: AJAX, what are the advantages of that relative to using an IFRAME?

Comment: iFrames are fast becoming extinct as a result of methods such as AJAX. They are horribly old fashioned and cumbersome, as you are experiencing here! Obviously there are some good points about them, e.g. a upload form, no page refresh required. However, the bad points far outweigh the good points and for this case it sounds like ajax would be a much better option.

Comment: thanks, you mentioning just redrawing the iframe solved it for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I actually ran into this problem last Friday. Your problem is most likely with the type of `.hide()` and `.show()` methods you're using. I didn't look into it too deeply, but it seems that when you use an effect and/or a direction in your hide show it forces the iframe to reload.

I got around this by changing to an `.animate()` method.

Your hide method might look like this instead:

`helpIframe.animate({ right: [number of pixels], opacity: 0.0 }, 1000);`

Then your show method might look like this:

`helpIframe.animate({ right: 0, opacity: 1.0 }, 1000);`

I had to add a callback inside the "hide" with an actual `.hide()` and add a `.show()` before animating back to skirt some opacity issues in IE7 and IE8, but it seemed to keep my iframe from reloading.

Hope that helps! :)